# AS3 Check if variable is String outputs MouseEvent info

Tags: actionscript-3

**UPDATE:** I found a workaround using different code. I am leaving this question in cause someone wants to answer why this was happening and maybe it can help someone else as well. Thanks

---

I am trying to check if a variable is a string, in this case if it has a url in the string. But the code is executing and in the trace statement I get this:

```
if (theWebsite is String)
trace(theWebsite);
```

**output:**
[MouseEvent type="click" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=3 localX=2259.8671875 localY=2485.85205078125 stageX=1003.25 stageY=71 relatedObject=null ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false buttonDown=false delta=0 commandKey=false controlKey=false clickCount=0]
MainStage? [object Main_Activate] and website? [MouseEvent type="click" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=3 localX=2259.8671875 localY=2485.85205078125 stageX=1003.25 stageY=71 relatedObject=null ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false buttonDown=false delta=0 commandKey=false controlKey=false clickCount=0]

Here is the code that creates this variable.

1.

```
MenuScreen.One_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, webViewButton("http://www.MyWebsite.com"));
```

2.

```
public function webViewButton(theWebsite:String):Function  {
            trace("made it here: " + theWebsite); /// output: www.MyWebsite.com
            return function(e:MouseEvent):void {
                trace("made it here too: " + theWebsite); //output: www.MyWebsite.com
            removeMenuScreen(theWebsite);
            }
        }
```

3.

```
public function removeMenuScreen(theWebsite:String = null, e: Event = null) {

            if (theWebsite is String) {
                trace("But did I make it here? " + theWebsite);
                // OUTPUTS all the above code mentioned earlier. 
            }
```

I am using that function for other things as well so that is why its set up that way.  **HOW can I fix this to have that code execute only if it is a defined string?** Thanks for any tips.

Comment: "I am using that function for other things..." -- Well, the problem is with those "other things". The code you posted will not produce the output you posted.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does *not* produce the output you posted.

What *would* produce the "`[MouseEvent ...]`" output is if you had something like `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeMenuScreen)`. Why? Because a `MouseEvent` will get coerced to its string value since the `removeMenuScreen` handler's first parameter `theWebsite` is of type `String`.

So, to answer your question: *it already is* only being executed when `theWebsite` is a string. And it will *only* ever be a string, or `null`, otherwhise if coercion to a string is not possible it will throw a runtime error.

If you want to avoid runtime coercion, make the parameter untyped:

```
public function removeMenuScreen(theWebsite:* = null) {
    if (theWebsite is String) {
        trace("But did I make it here? " + theWebsite);
    } else if (theWebsite is MouseEvent) {
        trace("Or did I make it here?", theWebsite)
    }
}
```

I don't recommend you go down this path, though, because it adds a lot of unclarity, which leads to bugs and hard debugging.